# Chrome browser back button doesn't refresh page in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

I used the above code to try and force a refresh when back button is pressed but it doesn't refresh the page only in chrome. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code. Sometime it works in local but never in production.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])   onPopStateBack() {     
   console.log("Back Button detected!");     
   window.location.reload();  
}   

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])   onPopState(event: any) {     
   console.log("Back Button detected!");     
   window.location.reload();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Angular's Router Service. Which seems to me, the more 'Angular' approach. In your constructor inject the Router Service and then subscribe to its events. The property navigationTrigger identifies the event event that triggered the navigation, in your case we are looking for the back button so we only need the 'popstart'.

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.refreshOnBackButtonClick();
}

refreshOnBackButtonClick(): void {
   this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
     if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
       console.log('popstart');
       window.location.reload();
     }
   });
}
```

Note: this will subscribe will also fire the event when the forward button is pressed in the browser. So you'll have to determine which event was fired if you want to refresh only when user clicks on back button. P.S there are additional properties in event object which can help you determine if you want to.